# HTML/JavaScript Linking

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

This question may have been asked before, but I had trouble finding an answer, since I didn't quite know what search terms to use.

In HTML, how do you make a link go a place, but execute JavaScript **instead** when it is clicked? Right now, I have a link that's somewhat like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:dostuff()">Stuff</a>
```

But, the thing is, when someone right clicks the link, I want them to be able to copy a direct URL to the link. Also, if someone's browser does not support JavaScript, or they have it disabled, I would still like them to be able to reach the page. Is it just

```
<a href="http://linkhere" onclick="javascript:dostuff()">Stuff</a>?
```

Or is there something more complicated?

Thanks!

Comment: As for gracefully degrading with no Javascript support, I think this article will be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Graceful_degradation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="http://linkhere" onclick="return dostuff()">Stuff</a>
```

Make sure that the dosuff function returns false if you want the link to not be followed when the script runs.

(The 'javascript:' is pointless. It [labels a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Loop_Statements/Label_Statement), but you don't have a loop. See the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1) for how to specify which language is being used in the intrinsic event handler attributes — better yet, use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive%5FJavaScript) and [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)).

Comment: Alright then, I feel stupid for not just trying that first. I assumed it was more complicated :p

Comment: You may also wish to modify that to onclick="dostuff(); return false".  This keeps the browser from following the link when you click on it.

Comment: No, the question was about running the JS and not following the link, sorry if I wasn't clear. I just wanted the link to appear on the status bar at the bottom of the screen and be copyable/follow-able in a new tab.

Thanks Jason!

Comment: Updated in response to the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the event return **false** to block the default action.

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">
```